# Angular assign 2 roles in a routing Role Based Authorization

Tags: angular, mean-stack

I am creating a mean stack application and i want to add a Role Based Authorization in some routing modules, i managed to do that but i couldn't assign multiple roles in one authorization
this is m hasRole guard :

```
canActivate(
route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {

const isAuthorized= this.user.role.includes(route.data.role);
if (!isAuthorized){
  window.alert('ALERT : you are not authorized !!')
}
 return isAuthorized;


}
```

and this is the code in the component code :

```
{
path: 'listuser',
component: ListUsersComponent,
canActivate:[HasRoleGuard],
data:{
  role:"Admin"
}
```

}

i want to add two roles Admin and Manager
i tried

```
data:{
  role:["Admin"||"Manager"]
}
```

but it didn't work

Comment: You can use a library also: https://casl.js.org/v5/en/package/casl-angular

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all you should do it like this:

```js
data:{
  roles:["Admin", "Manager"]
}
```

and then you have to check it like this:

```js
const intersectedRoles = this.user.role.filter(value => route.data.roles.includes(value));
const isAuthorized= intersectedRoles.length? true : false;
```